# Opensource Software For Security Video Recording

Tags: video, open-source, video-capture

Is there some opensource software I can use for recording video from a security camera?

Comment: Not really  . I think there is a special Linux Distro though that works like a CCTV security centre.. cant remeber the name now ..

Comment: Depends on the device, which operating system you have, etc. Can you give us some more information?

Comment: sorry no specific device and system, im looking to build one so i was wondering whats out there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[zoneminder](http://www.zoneminder.com/) I believe this is OSS, and should do the job. It's pretty well known and a beefy solution.

Comment: I'll second zoneminder.  I've used it before and it's got quite a few features and supports a wide number of cameras.

Answer (score 0):

You can have [motion](http://www.lavrsen.dk/foswiki/bin/view/Motion/WebHome) activated cameras that record only when there is activity.